# How to fix a bug where my Android app keeps crashing on start, does not open? (see description for more details)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

This is the full logcat info:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                       at cmput301.subbook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
>                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
>                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
>                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

These are the relevant files:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="cmput301.subbook.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit App"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainText"
        android:background="#e6a1a1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <!-- <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

        android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="504dp"
        android:text="Add New Subscription"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" /> -->


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package cmput301.subbook;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    import java.util.List;



    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private TextView text;
        private List<String> subListVal;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);

            ArrayList<String> subListVal = new ArrayList<String>();
          //  subListVal = new ArrayList<String>();

            subListVal.add("Netflix");
            subListVal.add("Github");
            subListVal.add("Spotify");
            subListVal.add("Gym");


          /*  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String>(this, R.layout.list_rows, R.id.listText, subListVal);

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter); */

            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(subListVal, this);

            //handle listview and assign adapter
            ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            lView.setAdapter(adapter);

           /* Button add_btn = new Button(this);
            add_btn.setText("Add New");
            lView.addFooterView(add_btn); */

        }


        }
```

**list_rows.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#ffe600" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Delete" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="Edit" />



    </LinearLayout>
```

**CustomerAdapter.java**

```
package cmput301.subbook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by thesh on 2/3/2018.
 */

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return list.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rows, null);
        }

        //Handle TextView and display string from your list
        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        Button editBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.edit_btn);

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                list.remove(position); //or some other task
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }


}
```

Literally my app was working, and suddenly I got this bug, without changing much. The last change I made was trying to add a button at the footer_view of the list. I tried googling the logchat error to no avail.

Would appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference at cmput301.subbook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
```

This is telling you that line 49 in `MainActivity` has your problem, in a `setAdapter()` call, where you are calling it on something that is `null`.

That would appear to be this line:

```
lView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

That means `lView` is `null`.

You attempt to assign a value to `lView` in the preceding line:

```
ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

If `lView` is `null`, then `findViewById(android.R.id.list)` is returning `null`. This means that Android cannot find a widget in your layout that has an `android:id` value of `@android:id/list`.

That is because your `ListView` has a different ID value:

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainText"
    android:background="#e6a1a1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
```

These need to line up. So, either:

- Change `android:id` in the `<ListView>` to `@android:id/list`, or
- Change your `findViewById()` call to look for `R.id.listView`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am pretty new to android studio+Java, so I didn't notice this obvious mistake. The fact that you explained your thought process is very helpful, now I can try to think the same way while doing Android dev. :)

Answer (score 0):

change this `ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);`

to `ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);`

Answer (score 0):

**Change** -

```
ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

**with** -

```
ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
```